# Let the topological space $X_n$ be obtained from $S^n$ by identifying three distinct points. Find the fundamental group of $X_n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let the topological space $X_n$ be obtained from $S^n$ by identifying three distinct points, i.e. $X_n = S^n/\{p, q, r\}.$  Find the fundamental group of $X_n$.

Comment: Seifert-van Kampen theorem should be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Your space is homotopically equivalent to $S^n \bigvee_2 S^1$ (i've used a little bit exotic notation, it's the wedge sum of $S^n$ with two copies of $S^1$), can you see how?

Comment: Not really, could you help me a little?

Comment: I suppose that you know that if you have a cw-complex $X$ and a subcomplex $A$ which is contractible then the map $X \to X/A$ is an homotopy equivalence (chapter 0 of Hatcher). You can think of your space as a copy of $S^n$ whith three segment whith one extremity respectively in a point of {p,q,r} and the other in common, after having collapsed them to a point  (example 0.8 is almost this case)